# Is C a part of the .NET framework?

Tags: .net-framework, c++, c

I've searched the net for this, but I couldn't really find an answer. I've found this though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875057.aspx

It says that C++ is a part of the .NET framework, and the headline says "C/C++", but there wasn't much about C, so I wasn't able to understand if it is or not.

Comment: Article by the way as very little to do with the .NET Framework.  It specifically about Microsoft’s C/C++ compiler contained within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It says that C++ is a part of the .NET framework

Actually, it does not.  It says Visual C++ is part of the .NET Framework.

Additionally, Visual Studio, can compile C and C++ code using Microsoft’s implementation of the respective standards.

> This section of the documentation includes guidelines and reference content for the Microsoft implementation of the ISO standards for C and C++.

.Net Framework does not contain C or C++, Visual C++ is an object oriented implementation of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework is an object oriented programming framework meant to be used with languages that it provides bindings for. Since C is not an object oriented language it wouldn't make sense to use it with the framework. Microsoft does provide its own version of C++ (that is incompatible with standard C++) to be used with the .NET Framework.

Answer (score -1):

C and C++ are both low level, you can always write code in C and C++ that would work with other languages. The main language for the .NET I think is C#. I don't think it's necessary for you to write C++ code for a .NET project. And if you had to, then you wouldn't need to ask this, because you would know that your question doesn't even make sense. Of course, since you don't know your question is ok.

So in a sense, `C` and `C++` are part of everything, and you can always write code in low level languages with interfaces for higher level ones like `C#` with `.NET` support. But that is quite specialized and is rarely needed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please consider combining your two answers. While there are cases where one poster can post multiple answers to a question, I don't think yours is one. Please take a minute to take the [tour] as well.

Comment: There are so many tiny technicalities that are just simply wrong within this answer.  You self-answered your own question and within your answer said “And if you had to, then you wouldn't need to ask this, because you would know that your question doesn't even make sense. ” which makes no sense.  **You basically attacked yourself** which is more weird then “not nice”